# guess a random 4 digit number with markers

Tags: python-3.x

I am comparing two lists and I need to show what elements in the list are equal and are of the same index. I was able to get the indices of the equal elements but I don't know how to count how many elements are equal and of the same indices.how can i put the indices into a list or tuple? ex. a= [1,2,3,4], b=[1,2,0,0], match = 2

for y in a:
            if y in b:
                if guesses_list.index(y) == number.index(y):

here if I print y will give me the elements that are matching from each list but I need to count how many elements matched.

Comment: i already got this

import random 

secret_number = (random.randint(999,10000))
number = [int(x) for x in str(secret_number)]
A = 10
B = 7
C = 5
difficulty = 0
guess = 1

Comment: print(number)

print("Please select difficulty: \nA) EASY \nB) AVERAGE \nC) DIFFICULT")
choice = input("\nChoice: ").upper()


if choice == "A":
    print("\nYou have", A, "guesses.")
    while guess <= A:
        print("\nGuess #", guess, end=": ")
        guess += 1
        guesses = input()
        guesses_list = [int(i) for i in str(guesses)]
        for y in number:
            if y in guesses_list :
                if guesses_list.index(y) == number.index(y):                    
                    print(number.index(y))

Comment: i just need to know how to convert the similar indices to something for me to count them

Comment: Please look into [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) around here!

Comment: Instead of adding comments, please edit your post to include your code.

Comment: Please put the code into the question. It's very hard to read in the restricted formatting of comments, and the question should be self-contained.